# Alternatives to using Thread.Sleep for waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading, wait, thread-sleep

Firstly I am not asking the same question as [C# - Alternative to Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450353/c-sharp-alternative-to-thread-sleep), or [Alternative to Thread.Sleep in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118414/alternative-to-thread-sleep-in-c). I don't think I am using it incorrectly and need a genuine alternative for specific situations.

During a code analysis run I saw a surprising violation coming up:

> Usage of Thread.Sleep() is a sign of flawed design.

This violation leads to [Peter Richie's article](https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/) on why exactly this constitutes bad design.

We all know thread creation is expensive and blocking in threads means contention on the pool. We also know that each thread will allocate a meg of memory so it should have a short lifespan, blocking on the UI is evil, using sleep for timing is unreliable etc etc etc. Which leads me to my point, if you really need to perform a sleep, what should you be using if not Thread.Sleep?

Peter goes on to mention that a zero sleep is the only correct use of Thread.Sleep effectively giving up the thread's timeslice and allowing other threads to process. And then even more scary is that this is only a because of limitations on unmanaged threads and if re-implemented in the CLR will create side effects of using Thread.Sleep in your applications. All the points on common bad usage are, in fact, good examples of bad usage.

I have the following situations in production code that uses Thread.Sleep quite successfully:

- Waiting for a file lock to be relinquished by the operating system (catch file lock problems, **wait for a second**, try again, give up after a while).
- Killing a process and waiting for it not to show up in the process list (kill it, check it's not running, **wait for a second**, check it not still running, force it closed).
- Waiting for copy buffers to flush (check a file size, try to access it, **wait**, check if size has changed).

Without using Thread.Sleep in situations like these, what other options do I have? Tight loops tend to make things worse and I don't believe this makes it's usage a "design flaw" especially since nothing is on the UI and only in background threads. It is just the nature of software to wait for other things in a multi-threaded environment with external factors affecting your code, sometimes you need to wait...

Comment: What do you want to say, Thread.Sleep is inevitable? then use it. But I never want to use it.

Comment: While Peter's article has many good points, it does not excuse the fact that it's just plain wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`WaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) type and derived types provide an event-driven mechanism for waiting that ties into the operating system. For example, when you have a `Task<T> task` and you wait on the result by accessing `task.Result`, the internal implementation isn't polling with `Thread.Sleep` calls in between. It's using a `WaitHandle`-derived type to do waiting and synchronization.

Sometimes a polling-based approach is necessary, as in some of the examples you gave in your bullet list, but often you *can* use an event-driven approach instead. It's not that `Thread.Sleep` is ***always*** bad - it's just that it is **very often misused**.

> It is just the nature of software to wait for other things in a multi-threaded environment with external factors affecting your code, sometimes you need to wait...

To ***wait*** is fine. To ***wait with polling*** is often not (*). If there is any way you can use an ***event-driven wait***, you should typically strive to use that.

I don't have a very good feel for exactly what it is that you're asking, so I won't elaborate beyond this. If you leave a comment I can expand my answer.

---

(*) The theoretical reason ***waiting with polling*** is bad is as follows:

Suppose I have code that looks like this:

```
//START
Begin();
while (!Done())
    Thread.Sleep(D);
//STOP
```

`Begin()` starts some operation. `Done()` returning `true` means the operation has finished.  Suppose this will happen after approximately `T` time. Then:

- The thread wakes up and checks the condition (calls `Done()`) `T/D` times
- The duration from `START` to `STOP` includes an expected `D/2` purely because of the `Thread.Sleep`

What value of `D` should you choose?  As you increase `D`, the expected duration form `START` to `STOP` increases linearly.  As you decrease `D`, the (bound on the) number of iterations increases as `1/D`. Both of these are bad, and finding the right `D` is problematic.

Now compare this to an ***event-driven wait***:

```
//START
Begin();
WaitDone();
//STOP
```

Theoretically speaking, as long as `WaitDone()` somehow magically waits until the operation has finished but no longer, both of the problems identified in the ***waiting with polling*** case have disappeared: this thread waits for exactly the right amount of time - no more, no less!

To reiterate the point I started with: in .NET, the `WaitHandle` class and derived types are what facilitate this approach.

Comment: Probably because the downvoter is clueless. +1 for excellent answer, esp. for 'not that Thread.Sleep is always bad - it's just that it is very often misused'.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this as the best answer simply because it excuses me for using Thread.Sleep in my particular context :) and also highlights to everyone that WaitHandle is an optimal way to wait for threads to finish. I use ResetEvents often since I can't wait for a signal and timeout quite easily, however, in these handful of cases I haven't been able to escape the allure of just using a Thread.Sleep. Take this code for for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774412/relog-cant-open-a-binary-log-file-if-executed-from-c-sharp/16775074#16775074, I need a slow-down not to kill the OS

Comment: @BrutalDev If the thing you are interfacing with doesn't support even-driven asynchronous operations, the only way to perform certain operations is through polling. For example, in Windows 7 and earlier, the Windows APIs simply do not allow you to *wait* for a file lock; but in Windows 8, the WinRT APIs have been redesigned to natively support event-driven asynchronous operations.

Comment: @BrutalDev - the usual bodge for 'wait until file completely written' is for the 'source' app to write the file into a 'temp' folder and, when it has finally closed it, MOVE it to the folder which is being monitored by the 'monitoring' app.  Of course, if the source app is opaque, frozen or otherwise cannot be modified to perform the move of the completed file, you're a bit stuft, yes :(

Comment: Sadly this is still .NET 4.0 or less :(

Comment: @MartinJames: In a perfect world all apps would copy/write data temporarily and move it. Generalized file monitoring could mean the end-user could be copying with hundreds of different applications none of which are predicable in terms of flushing buffers or closing file locks. So being "stuft" is quite accurate. At least I can ignore those particular violations in confidence that I know what I'm doing and I can bend the rules here. I would normally use event based waiting so this answer in terms of an accurate alternative to general "bad" usage is correct IMHO.

Comment: @BrutalDev - yes.  If a design is bad, but it's the only design, or the least bad design, it's the correct design :)

Comment: `Task<TResult>.Result` doesn't use its `WaitHandle`.  The handle is actually avoided at all costs.  It uses `ManualResetEventSlim.Wait`, which uses `Monitor.Wait` (this one might end up using a Win32 event in Microsoft's implementation).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you said most of it. Quoting "We all know thread creation is expensive and blocking in threads means contention on the pool", so you even understand what using a pool of threads is about.

You also understand that blocking the UI thread is bad.

Looking at the pool of threads model again: you have a pool of threads, maybe one per processor, and then pass tasks to them. What sense would it make for one of those threads to block? If it does not have work to perform now, then it should simply proceed to a different task.

So, going directly to your question "Which leads me to my point, if you really need to perform a sleep, what should you be using if not Thread.Sleep?", in a modern well designed program, you would never need to do it, you would simply schedule a task for latter.

You should think of the threads in a pool, much as the processors in a system, as resources, which should be released to others when not needed.

Going to your examples, you're a bit too involved in the imperative programming paradigm.

- You don't need to wait for a process to disappear... I don't imagine why you need this, but if have to wait, it's because you have work to perform after sometime, the "continuation" of your function. You should set up a timer for this "continuation".
- The file examples should have other mechanisms for it, if they do not have.... that would be good OS design. For instance, the only safe way to wait for buffers to flush would be an OS primitive, on the likes of fsync.
- If there is someone writing to a file and then another reading from the file, then a synchronization mechanism is needed, not a timed wait (unless the file is append-only, in which case the file itself is the synchronization mechanism).

Waiting on a synchronization mechanism is not "bad".

Comment: Thank you, good points. To elaborate on the points: 1. Waiting for the app to die is just for reliability, so the check will ensure that it does close gracefully otherwise it will force it. 2. The problem here is there is nothing from the OS (at least in managed code) that tells you when a file write is complete. Looks at this for an example on how it's almost unavoidable to slow down and wait for the OS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774412/relog-cant-open-a-binary-log-file-if-executed-from-c-sharp/16775074#16775074 3. An anti-virus is an example that would lock unexpectedly.

Answer (score -1):

In one of my projects I used 2 threads and I had problem with UI freezing thnx to Thread.Sleep ....this fixed my problem:

```
    public static void Sleeping(int miliseconds)
    {
        var task = Sleep(miliseconds);
        task.Wait();
    }

    public static async Task Sleep(int miliseconds)
    {
        await Task.Delay(miliseconds);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

as Darky711  recommended, the much better way is:

```
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
```

Comment: Task.Delay(1000).Wait() is a good alternative to Thread.Sleep(1000).
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084603/3115559 for a good explanation.