# Why does this program write a blank line instead of a string value?

Tags: c#, async-await

When I ran the following code (which I was asked during a C# interview), it did not output anything.

Can somebody explain this behavior?

```
class Program {
  private static string result;

  static void Main() {
    SaySomething();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }

  static async Task<string> SaySomething() {
    await Task.Delay(5);
    result = "Hello world!";
    return “Something”;
  }
}
```

I thought this method should output `result`, because I am calling

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

after the `SaySomething()` method call completed

Comment: You're not waiting for `SaySomething` to finish.

Comment: You should know how await / async work if you are going to use it in your code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Your are executing `Console.WriteLine(result);` before your fire&forget  task  is executing the assignment.

Comment: @Igor He said it was an interview question, not that he's actively writing code using it. That said, it's still a good resource to read.

Comment: @Igor I'm not much familiar with asynchronous programming. Any way the link you referred is good one to read.

Answer (score 2):

Because `SaySomething` is `async` it will yield control of the thread to the caller when you hit the `await Task.Delay(5)` and thus hit the `Console.WriteLine(result)` before it changes the value of `result`.  Just change it to `SaySomething().Wait();` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This program would have written something to console, if you had given the `Task<string>` enough time to complete. Currently, however, the program exists before `SaySomething()` finishes.

To fix this problem, make sure that you wait for the `Task<string>`:

```
static void Main() {
    MainAsync().Wait();
}
private static async Task MainAsync() {
    var retVal = await SaySomething().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", retVal, result);
}
```

Note that your current version also ignores the result returned by your asynchronous task. The example above stores the return value in `retVal` variable, and prints it along with the the `result` stored by `SaySomething` in the static variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SaySomething()` method is `async`. Your `Console.WriteLine(results)` is getting called before the task completed. You can do one of a couple of things.

You can call your function like this:

```
SaySomething().Wait();
```

Or you could break your process out like this:

```
private static string result;

    static void Main()
    {
        CallSaySomething();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<string> SaySomething()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
        result = "Hello world!";
        return "Something";
    }

    static string CallSaySomething()
    {
        var task = SaySomething();
        task.Wait();

        var result = task.Result;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If i replace await Task.Delay(5); with await Thread.Sleep(5); then it will write "Hello world!". This is the point where i got confused. Can you explain why is it so ?

Comment: @JaganMohanReddy take a look at this SO post to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the `Task` returned by `SaySomething` to complete.  As soon as the `await Task.Delay(5)` runs the `SaySomething` returns to `Main`.  At this point `result` as not been set, so Console.WriteLine`prints an empty string.  Then your application ends when`Main`exits and the task started in`SaySomething` never completes.

You want this instead:

```
class Program {
  private static string result;

  static void Main() {
    SaySomething().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }

  static async Task<string> SaySomething() {
    await Task.Delay(5);
    result = "Hello world!";
    return “Something”;
  }
}
```

In the normal case however you would want `await SaySomething();` instead of blocking, but `Main` is not allowed to be an async method.