# If Task.Delay is to be prefered over Thread.Sleep, why examples in this book use Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am reading Exam Ref 70-483: Programming in C# by Wouter de Kort.
The writer doesn't explicitly mention the version of C#, but I guess it's 5.0 since he makes heavy use of async/await keywords.

The examples in this book only use Thread.Sleep() and not Task.Delay()

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
});
```

,

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    bag.Add(42);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    bag.Add(21);
});
```

etc etc...

From other reading/SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep), I'd figure that

```
await Task.Delay(1000)
```

should generally do better in a parallel context than

```
Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

because Task.Delay leaves it's thread unhindered thus allowing other tasks execute on it.
I've just Ctrl-F'd the book and it didn't find a single occurrence for Task.Delay!
I'm confused between community opinions from the internet and official Microsoft book.
**If Task.Delay is a good practice, why doesn't this book address it in any way?**
Or did I miss something?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask the author of the book?

Comment: In order to use Task.Delay(1000) you have to use 'await ' which it forces your method to be async. Sometimes this is not a good approach. But you always can use Thread.Sleep() with no restrictions.

Comment: `Task.Delay` is simply an awaitable version of `Thread.Sleep` for exactly the reasons you state, so the thread resource is freed to have other work scheduled to it. Simply, book code tends to be moderately good to follow but can drop the ball in the odd place. Review the book's errata online (if it has one), and review other sources such as articles or blog posts to get further opinions and explanations. No one book is the single source of truth for good programming practice and sometimes a book misses something or gets it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep) deals with real-world code; what you have in your book are code examples, which are quite different.

For code examples:

`Thread.Sleep` is appropriate if you *want* to block the current thread - i.e., you're simulating some synchronous / CPU-bound work.

`Task.Delay` is appropriate if you *don't* want to block the current thread - i.e., you're simulating some asynchronous / I/O-bound work.

For the particular examples you posted (code in `Parallel.For` and `Task.Run`), I'd say `Thread.Sleep` is the most appropriate. `Parallel.For` and `Task.Run` are specifically for running CPU-bound code on different threads, so a synchronous "placeholder" of `Thread.Sleep` is correct.

Note that in real-world code, any "placeholder" usages of `Thread.Sleep` and `Task.Delay` like this are replaced with real code.

In real-world code, `Task.Delay` is still useful for things like delayed retries. `Thread.Sleep` should not be in real-world code.

Comment: Sir, thank you kindly for clearing it up for me. I misunderstood that Thread.Sleep is there to so simulate CPU-Bound work. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Exam 70-483 is for Visual Studio 2012, when C# had no async/await.

Also, the `Thread.Sleep()` is just there to indicate work being done.

Comment: async/await is explained and used in the book,as I wrote in the question. Also I think the exam is for language, not IDE.