# GUI is freezed till all tasks are finished

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm stuck with await. I want my task to report some progress to gui with fashion way - ContinueWith and FromCurrentSynchronizationContext.

But GUI is blocked and does not refresh untill all tasks are completed. How do I fix this problem?

I think the reason is because tasks are running in the same pool and refresh gui tasks are added to the end of the queue. But, I don't know how to do it properly due to lack of experience

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace AsyncCallbackSample
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private readonly Random _random = new Random();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void OnGoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            await Task.WhenAll(_listBox.Items
                .OfType<string>() 
                .Select(
                    taskArgument => 
                    Task
                        .FromResult(DoLongTermApplication(taskArgument))
                        .ContinueWith(previousTask => _listBox.Items[_listBox.Items.IndexOf(taskArgument)] = previousTask.Result, uiScheduler) // refreshing the gui part while all other staff is in progress.
                        )
                .ToArray());
        }

        private string DoLongTermApplication(string taskInformation)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000 + _random.Next(1000));
            return $"Processed {taskInformation}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're scheduling on the UI thread with the current synchronization context.

Comment: Thanks but how to do it properly, i'm a newbie with that staff.

Comment: You really should not be mixing async/await and `.ContinueWith(`, stick with one or the other.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, thanks for pointing to it. But i am newbie with Tasks and don't know how to make it in a shining way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Thread.Sleep` when you want to block current (UI in your case) thread.
See: [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Try something along these lines:

```
 private async void OnGoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            await Task.WhenAll(_listBox.Items
                .OfType<string>() 
                .Select(
                    taskArgument => 
                    Task.Run(async () => await DoLongTermApplicationAsync(taskArgument))
                        .ContinueWith(previousTask => _listBox.Items[_listBox.Items.IndexOf(taskArgument)] = previousTask.Result, uiScheduler) // refreshing the gui part while all other staff is in progress.
                        )
                .ToArray());
   }

   private async Task<string> DoLongTermApplicationAsync(string taskInformation)
   {
        await Task.Delay(1000 + _random.Next(1000));
        return $"Processed {taskInformation}";
   }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. As i understood problem in my code was that i needed to launch in default TaskFactory the initial task that was lambda. Also thanks for hinting about Task.Delay. I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 3):

You should follow these guidelines:

- Don't use `ContinueWith`, ever. Use `await` instead.
- Don't use `TaskScheduler`s, unless you absolutely *have* to. Use `await` instead.
- Use `Task.Run` to run synchronous code on a thread pool thread. `Task.FromResult` is not appropriate for this.

Combining these:

```
private async void OnGoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.WhenAll(_listBox.Items.OfType<string>() 
      .Select(taskArgument => ProcessAsync(taskArgument)));
}

private async Task ProcessAsync(string taskArgument)
{
  var result = await Task.Run(() => DoLongTermApplication(taskArgument));
  _listBox.Items[_listBox.Items.IndexOf(taskArgument)] = result;
}

private string DoLongTermApplication(string taskInformation)
{
  Thread.Sleep(1000 + _random.Next(1000));
  return $"Processed {taskInformation}";
}
```

Alternatively, if your `DoLongTermApplication` can be made truly asynchronous (e.g., by replacing `Thread.Sleep` with `Task.Delay`), then you don't need `Task.Run` either:

```
private async void OnGoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.WhenAll(_listBox.Items.OfType<string>() 
      .Select(taskArgument => ProcessAsync(taskArgument)));
}

private async Task ProcessAsync(string taskArgument)
{
  var result = await DoLongTermApplicationAsync(taskArgument);
  _listBox.Items[_listBox.Items.IndexOf(taskArgument)] = result;
}

private async Task<string> DoLongTermApplicationAsync(string taskInformation)
{
  await Task.Delay(1000 + _random.Next(1000)).ConfigureAwait(false);
  return $"Processed {taskInformation}";
}
```

Since you're new to `async`, I recommend reading my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and following up with my [MSDN article on `async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Wov, i didn't expect such a huge comment even with code snippets and best pratice links for my problems with code... Thanks.