# Sending data to a notepad using processes

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to send every item from my listbox to a notepad,but my logic is kinda beating me.

```
private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad");

    if (notepad != null)
    {
        if (IsIconic(notepad.MainWindowHandle))
            ShowWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle, 9);

        SetForegroundWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle);
        string text = "";

        foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            text = item.ToString();
            Clipboard.SetText(text);
            SendKeys.Send("^V");
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }
    }
}
```

In my logic this should send every item from the listbox to a notepad every item on a different line.But that doesn't happen every time,sometimes it just sends the only the last item from the listbox as many items there are in the listbox. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try slowing down the pasting part, possibly a sleep, I feel like you're trying to paste too fast.

Comment: didn't think about that,really good tip :)

Comment: Instead of sending individual items, just use `String.Join` to combine all of them in a single string, eg `String.Join("\n",listBox1.Items)`

Comment: and if I join them in a single string how can I send them each on a line?

Comment: @JohnPietrar By adding newlines `\n` after every item.

Comment: A line is something that ends with a line separator, ie `String.Join("\n",listBox1.Items)`. Your current code doesn't paste line separators as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An another option you can find the [`Edit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458(v=vs.85).aspx) control of notepad using [`FindWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) and send a [`WM_SETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx) message to it using [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx). This way you don't need to bring the notepad window to front.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
    string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Find notepad by its name, or use the instance which you opened yourself
    var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
    if(notepad!=null)
    {
        var edit = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
        SendMessage(edit, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "This is a Text!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is more elegant than using sendkeys to send the string or paste the string. It also works if the notepad application is minimized. Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: I am asking you to help because I know you can give proper explanations step by step, not only answer it and maybe I can close this `winhandle` topic once and for all.

Comment: The idea which comes to my mind at the moment is: You can use `EnumChildWindows` in a timer `Tick` event and check if the title of a child window is `Page Setup` (may be and its class name is `#32770 (Dialog)`) then do the job that you want.

Comment: I have even more questions now lol ... could you post an answer there if I ask nicely please ,so I can understand better ?

Comment: I posted the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample test, it works if you change SendKeys.Send to SendKeys.SendWait

```
    List<string> data = new List<string>() { "Test", "hope", "It", "works","Or" };
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetText(item);
        //SendKeys.Send("^V");
        //SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

        SendKeys.SendWait("^V");
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    }
```

Because the key applied later than update Clipboard and loop, so that issue happend.

Comment: Did not know about the `SendKeys.SendWait` .Thank you for sharing this with me :)

Comment: seems that this doesn't work ,after like 40 tries I got that error again sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with InputSimulator, Package Manage Console:
Install-Package InputSimulator

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad");
                if (notepad != null)
                {
                    if (IsIconic(notepad.MainWindowHandle))
                        ShowWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle, 9);

                    var input = new InputSimulator();
                    SetForegroundWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle);
                    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
                    {
                        input.Keyboard.TextEntry(item.ToString());
                        input.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: And what does this exactly do?Could you explain in more detail please? :) because I never heard of InputSimulator

Comment: its a wrapper for Sending keys to application.they have managed the code for completion processing mechanism in that.

Comment: @JohnPietrar you can refer to this https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Better than using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep();`  use `await Task.Delay();` https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084603/6886308

Answer (score 0):

From @GillBates suggestion I used `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep();` and it seem to work great now.

```
private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad");

            if (notepad != null)
            {
                if (IsIconic(notepad.MainWindowHandle))
                    ShowWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle, 9);

                SetForegroundWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle);
                string text = "";

                foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    text = item.ToString();
                    Clipboard.SetText(text);
                    SendKeys.Send("^V");
                    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
                }

            }
}
```