# Having Time Delay in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This code is an algorithm search and goal is when table is ordered from 1 to 16 (in first of game table is not ordered) . I want to have a delay when it fills UI Table (The table that show result of the game in UI), because i want to show the player the process of solving game by algorithm. 
How can i have delay (1 or 2 seconds) in `//Make Delay`?

```
public bool BFS_TreeSearch(int[,] table, Queue<int[,]> fringe)
    {
        MakeNode(table, fringe);

        do
        {
            if (fringe.Count == 0)
                return false;
            int[,] node = fringe.Dequeue();

            //Make Delay


            FillTableUI(node);

            if (isGoal(node))
                return true;
            MakeNode(node, fringe);
        } while (true);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a synchronous or an asynchronous *sleep* by using `Thread.Sleep` or `Task.Delay` based on your requirements. As you want to show some things on UI, I think you should use the latter like this. Note that this will force you to make your method `async`, so you have to call it differently.

```
public async Task<bool> BFS_TreeSearch(int[,] table, Queue<int[,]> fringe)
{
    MakeNode(table, fringe);

    do
    {
        if (fringe.Count == 0)
            return false;
        int[,] node = fringe.Dequeue();

        await Task.Delay(2000) // continue from here after 2 seconds


        FillTableUI(node);

        if (isGoal(node))
            return true;
        MakeNode(node, fringe);
    } while (true);

}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep) also in this topic.