# How to correctly await a task within a task?

Tags: c#, task

I'm using [Flurl](https://flurl.io/) to make requests. Currently I have the following code and everything works fine:

```
public class Request()
{
    public async Task<Bitmap> GetImage(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new Url(url)
        {
            var content = await client.GetStringAsync();
            //return as image
        }
    }
}
```

And on the main UI thread I do:

```
public async void GetImages()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < someCounter; i++)
    {
        var img = await myRequest.GetImage(url);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

The above works but the UI thread sleeps for a while and I wanted to do the above within a task. So I did:

```
public async void GetImages()
{
    await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < someCounter; i++)
        {
            var img = await myRequest.GetImage(url);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });
}
```

However, with the above, the code stops at `await client.GetStringAsync();`. There's no exception, the code either stop execution there or waits for something.

Is what I'm trying to do correct or is there a better way. If it's correct, why does the inner await never completes?

Comment: Why are you sleeping `Thread.Sleep(100);` ?

Comment: Also why is this in a for loop anyway? you are just getting the same image `x` amount of time

Comment: @TheGeneral I need to make a slight delay between requests. This is a simplified version of the problem. In the actual method, I'm getting different images every request.

Comment: Ahh ok, understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use sleep, you should probably use `Task.Delay`. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep) will provide you with better insights on when to use `Thread.Sleep` and when to use  `Task.Delay`.

**Second**, in your code, What you should do, instead of await and sleep, is the following:

```
public async void GetImages()
{
   var tasks = new List<Task>();
   for (int i = 0; i < someCounter; i++)
   {
      tasks.Add(myRequest.GetImage(url));
   }
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Notice the [`WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2) call at the end of the `for` loop, which will create a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have completed.

Then, `ConfigureAwait(false)` tells the await that you do not need to resume on the current context (in this case, "on the current context" means "on the UI thread")

**Third**, in your call to the url, change it to `Task.Run`:

```
public class Request()
{
    public async Task<Bitmap> GetImage(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new Url(url)
        {
            //return as image
            var content = await Task.Run(() => client.GetStringAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

you use `Task.Run` to call the method, not as part of the implementation of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Thread.Sleep(100);`, it wont `await`, it wont give the thread back, it will just sit there doing nothing and holding up your *UI*

If anything, you should be using `Task.Delay`, it will play nice with a `async`, it wont block the *UI* thread and works on a *CallBack*.

Also, you should let your `async` `await` pattern propagate like a virus up to the event which started this, by returning `async Task` (and only then using `async void`)

```
public async Task GetImages()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < someCounter; i++)
    {
        var img = await myRequest.GetImage(url);
        // for your small wait.
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

If you are worried about all the state machines, in some cases you can just return the `Task` and not `await`.

Also, in your base library, there is no point returning to the captured context, so its suitable to call`ConfigureAwait(false);`, this will give you a slight efficiency

```
var content = await client.GetStringAsync()
                          .ConfigureAwait(false);
```