# List of Tasks Loop Start Offset

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am trying to loop through a list of tasks and offset the start of each task by a specific amount of seconds like:

```
Int32 delayTime = 1500;

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
// .... add stuff to task list.
tasks.ForEach(task =>
{
    Task.Delay(delayTime);
    task.Start();
    delayTime += 1500;
});
```

However, the above starts all tasks together not taking in account the task delay. Is there a way to stagger a list of tasks, or structure it differently so I can start each task a few seconds after the previous one starts?

Comment: you should await the task inside foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Delay` "Creates a cancellable task that completes after a specified time interval." ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.7.2)). So basically your `ForEach` loop starts a new Task that is going to wait for `delayTime` on its own thread and then you start `task` immediately after starting that delay.

You should either `await` that `Task.Delay` call

```
Int32 delayTime = 1500;

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
// .... add stuff to task list.
tasks.ForEach(async task =>
{
    await Task.Delay(delayTime);
    task.Start();
    delayTime += 1500;
});
```

use `Task.Delay(delayTime).Wait()`

```
Int32 delayTime = 1500;

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
// .... add stuff to task list.
tasks.ForEach(task =>
{
    Task.Delay(delayTime).Wait();
    task.Start();
    delayTime += 1500;
});
```

or use `Thread.Sleep(delayTime)` to put the current thread to sleep.

```
Int32 delayTime = 1500;

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
// .... add stuff to task list.
tasks.ForEach(task =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(delayTime);
    task.Start();
    delayTime += 1500;
});
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20082221/446515) to know when you should use `Delay` vs `Sleep`.

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the .Wait(). Now it is working. I did not want to put the actual thread to sleep in fear it may stop another task running on the same thread.