# How to simulate an expensive operation with async?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, console-application

Is the code from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth#deeper-dive-into-task-and-taskt-for-a-cpu-bound-operation) really the best way to simulate a long running task?

The console app I've worked up is fairly simple and seems to work just fine.

I'm not sure if I could swap out `DoExpensiveCalculation` for an an `Async` method, like `GetStringAsync` from `HttpClient` without issue.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExpensiveAsync
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("started");

            var t = CalculateResult("stuff and that");

            Console.WriteLine("press return");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task<string> CalculateResult(string data)
        {
            // This queues up the work on the threadpool.
            var expensiveResultTask = Task.Run(() => DoExpensiveCalculation(data));

            // Note that at this point, you can do some other work concurrently,
            // as CalculateResult() is still executing!

            Console.WriteLine("concurrent");

            // Execution of CalculateResult is yielded here!
            var result = await expensiveResultTask; // CalculateResult returns the Task object here

            Console.WriteLine("synchronous"); // this code runs once the DoExpensiveCalculation method has finished

            return result;
        }

        public static string DoExpensiveCalculation(string data)
        {
            var completionTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3);

            Console.WriteLine("begin");

            while (DateTime.Now < completionTime) ;

            Console.WriteLine("finish");

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "expensive". If you mean "takes some time to complete", you can just do `Task.Delay(15_000)` (15 seconds, adjust as needed). If you actually need it to consume cpu while it is running then you need to implement a busy wait loop that just keeps looping until enough time has elapsed, you can wrap such a loop in a task and use `Stopwatch` to figure out when to complete.

Comment: I had tried that with Thread.Sleep(), but that seems to sleep the calling code as well. What would be the critical difference between that and Task.Delay() (which I'm obviously not getting)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep

Comment: To observe how `async-await` works (I assume this is what you are trying to achieve by "logging" into console), make `Main` method asynchronous as well. Because in current implementation your application exits(prints: "press return") before task is complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the code implies that `DoExpensiveCalculation` is a CPU-bound operation. If you want to stub out a CPU-bound operation without taking up CPU, `Thread.Sleep` is the appropriate option.

> I'm not sure if I could swap out DoExpensiveCalculation for an an Async method, like GetStringAsync from HttpClient without issue.

Well, that's completely different. `GetStringAsync` is not a CPU-bound operation; it's an I/O-bound operation.

I/O-bound operations are naturally asynchronous, and they can be used directly with `async` and `await`. CPU-bound operations are naturally synchronous, so that's where you sometimes want to use `Task.Run`. "Sometimes" in this case generally means "when you're on a UI thread", so that the UI isn't frozen while the CPU-bound operation is running. When you wrap the CPU-bound operation in a `Task.Run`, you can then treat it as asynchronous, i.e., `await`ing it from the UI thread.

Your example code is a console app, where the use of `Task.Run` is usually not necessary. Console apps generally run whatever code they need to run and exit; in most cases there's no UI that needs to be kept responsive, and thus no need for `Task.Run`.