# Not seeing output after using Task delay

Tags: c#

I am using an online editor for testing some C# code : https://repl.it/
I am not able to get the task after Task.Delay. 
Why is this C# code not working as intended?

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Input {

   public Input() {

   }

   public async void  hello()
   {
    Console.WriteLine("some task");
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   Console.WriteLine("after some time");
     }


}

class SomeExample {
   public static void Main(string[] args) {

      Input std1 = new Input( );
      std1.hello();
   }
}
```

Comment: You have `async void` return type instead of `async Task`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes: Change your method return type from `void` to `Task`. Make the console wait by adding `Console.ReadLine()` so that you can see the output ("after some time") and lastly, tell the method to wait and don't finish execution by adding `Wait()`.
Hope this works.

```
class Input
{
    public Input()
    {

    }

    public async Task hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("some task");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("after some time");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class SomeExample
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Input std1 = new Input();
        std1.hello().Wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Method `hello` should return `Task`, not `void`. Method `Main` should be `async Task` to be able to await `hello`. Also you need to await `std1.hello()` call:

```
public async Task hello()
{
    Console.WriteLine("some task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("after some time");
}

public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
{
  Input std1 = new Input( );
  await std1.hello();
}
```

What you have now is situation when `Main` method finishes its execution before `hello` method (because it not awaited).

Comment: It does not seem to work here:
https://repl.it/@VishwasGagrani/TaskDelay

Comment: std1.hello().Wait() works.  But not   await std1.hello() ;

Comment: https://repl.it/@VishwasGagrani/TaskDelay - what is currently here is synchronous code which blocks main thread on `.Wait()`

Answer (score -1):

For now it seems this code is doing my work. I don't need to use async or Task keywords.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Input
{
    public Input()
    {

    }

    public void   hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("some task");
           Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("after some time");

    }


}

class SomeExample
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Input std1 = new Input();
        std1.hello() ;

    }
}
```

Comment: This code is synchronous. You don't need to use Task.Delay(1000).Wait. Instead you'd better use Thread.Sleep(1000). You would need async/Tasks if you want your code to be asynchronous. You could read this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413138/4553518