# Task.Delay vs Thread.Sleep difference

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

```cs
private static async Task MainFunc()
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    List<Task<int>> list = new List<Task<int>>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        list.Add(TaskFunc(i));
    }

    var taskResult = await Task.WhenAll(list);

    foreach (var item in taskResult)
    {
        Console.Write($"i= {item}.{ Environment.NewLine }");
    }

    list.Clear();

    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs1 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"Total execution time: { elapsedMs1 }");
    Console.WriteLine();


    watch.Restart();


    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        list.Add(Task.Run(() => ThreadFunc(i)));
    }

    var threadResult = await Task.WhenAll(list);

    foreach (var item in threadResult)
    {
        Console.Write($"i= {item}.{ Environment.NewLine }");
    }

    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs2 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"Total execution time: { elapsedMs2 }");
}

private static async Task<int> TaskFunc(int i)
{

    if (i == 1)
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    else if (i == 2)
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    else if (i == 3)
        await Task.Delay(5000);

    return i;
}

private static int ThreadFunc(int i)
{
    if (i == 1)
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    else if (i == 2)
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    else if (i == 3)
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

    return i;
}
```

In this example there are two functions, `TaskFunc` and `ThreadFunc`, which are called from `MainFunc` seperately. I am curious as to why the second method doesn't seem to have any effect, and seems to be skipped. Not even the `Thread.Sleep(...)` seems to get executed.

[image: Time comparison]

As you can see, the total execution time for `ThreadFunc` is very short, even though the sleep timers should be same for both methods. Also, `i` is always set to 4. I suppose that the main thread is doing something wrong. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is scoping. The `i` you are using inside the `Task.Run(() => TheadFunc(i))` is not a new integer, but rather, since it's a delegate, the value of `i` will only be retrieved *once the delegate is executed*.

This leads to `i` being 4 in all cases, since your `for`-loop increases it that much. But since you do not have an `if`-condition for a value of 4, it won't perform any delays with `Thread.Sleep(...)`.

Comment: Yes, I tested it for myself about delegate scoping and totally agreed. but second part of my question still can not understand why it does not work with if condition threed.sleep(...).

Comment: @user746499 I suggest that you add to your `ThreadFunc` a final else condition `else Thread.Sleep(10000)`, and see what happens then.