# Render mode does not work properly on blazor web assembly .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, render

This is my razor component page:

```
@page "/SignIn"
@inject INotificationService _localStorage
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
@inject IAuthenticationService _authService
@rendermode @(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false))

<Notification Notif="@Notification" />
<EditForm Model="SignInRequest" OnValidSubmit="SignInAction" FormName="SignInUser">
    ...
</EditForm>

@code {
    public bool PageLoading { get; set; }
    private Models.Notification? Notification { get; set; } = null;
    public SignInRequestDto SignInRequest { get; set; } = new();
    public bool IsAuthFailed { get; set; }
    public string ReturnURL { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        PageLoading = true;
        StateHasChanged();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        await GetNotification();
        PageLoading = false;
    }
...
```

So when I am on the Home page and I click "Se connecter" (that means sign in), the page does not goes to the signIn page, but instead stall on the Home page executing the `OnInitializeAsync` of the SignIn and then when it is finish, it shows finally the SingIn page.

I was expected that `prerender: false` will fix this but it does nothing.

This is the `MainLayout` that will redirect to the `/SignIn` page.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogOut">Se déconnecter</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="@Routes.SignIn">Se connecter</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    public void BeginLogOut()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateToLogout(Routes.Disconnect);
    }
}
```

This is the demo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15fd0P8a4cuyH1F6rg8B6CN7MBfeSVk16/view?usp=sharing

I expect that I will see the Loading component and the right page (`/signin`) instead of waiting on page Home before `OnInitializeAsync` is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the methods in `OnInitializedAsync` are all asynchronous.

Now you are using `prerender: false` to check the issue, and my suggestion is you should use `Stopwatch` to check the time-taken.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    PageLoading = true;
    StateHasChanged();
    await GetNotification();
    PageLoading = false;
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"OnInitializedAsync takes: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
}
```

We should use `await Task.Delay(3000);` like below , and then you'll find that the page will quickly jump to the landing page.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    PageLoading = true;
    StateHasChanged();
    //
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    await GetNotification();
    PageLoading = false;
}
```

**Related Link**

[When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084603/7687666)