Why is time running so slow on Android compared to windows in maui .net?
I’m developing a boxing app that plays the sound of a strike (as part of a combination) you’re meant to perform. However, I’ve encountered an issue: everything works perfectly on Windows, but when I run the app on Android, it’s like five times slower. The problem seems to stem from a method where await Task.Delay runs significantly slower on Android. It's my first bigger project, so I'm still figuring things out as I go.
  private async Task ExecuteStrikes(List<IStrike> currentStrikes, bool isAdvice, CancellationToken token)
  {
      foreach (var strike in currentStrikes)
      {
          await CheckPauseAsync(token); // Kontrola pauzy

          if (end || skipped || token.IsCancellationRequested) break;

          await StopAll(token);
          if (!skipped)
          {
              // Přímé volání metod bez zbytečného vytváření nových úloh.
              switch (strike)
              {
                  case PunchClass _:
                      await GenericSounds.PlayPunchSound(token);
                      break;
                  case DefenceClass _:
                      await Task.Delay(50, token);
                      await GenericSounds.PlayDefenceSound(token);
                      break;
                  case MoveClass _:
                      await Task.Delay(200, token);
                      await GenericSounds.PlayMoveSound(token);
                      break;
              }
              await Task.Delay(isAdvice ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(300 / 1), token);
          }
      }
  }

And here is my other method that calls "ExecuteStrikes" method
        private async Task ExecuteCombo(ComboClass combo, bool isAdvice, CancellationToken token)
        {
            int currentRep = 0;
            int adjKTime = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((double)combo.time / 1));

            for (int i = 0; i < combo.reps; i++)
            {
                await CheckPauseAsync(token); // Check pause before each iteration
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;

                currentRep++;
                if (!isAdvice)
                {
                    strike_label.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
                    await GenericSounds.PlayGoSound(token);
                }

                await Task.Delay(300, token);
                ChangeTextOnLabel(rep_label, $"{currentRep}/{combo.reps}");
                await Task.Run(() => ExecuteStrikes(combo.GetStrikes(), isAdvice, token));

                if (!isAdvice) await Task.Delay(1200, token);
            }
        }


And here is a method that calls the "ExecuteCombo" method
   async public void Action()
   {
       cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
       CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
       int currentComIndex = 0;
       int remainingRounds = workout.GetNumOfRounds();
       int currentRound = 1;
       double divisor = 1;

       // Zobrazení času na pozadí
       _ = Task.Run(() => ZobrazCas(token));

       try
       {
           skipped = false;

           await Task.Delay(2000, token);
           await GenericSounds.PlayGetReadySound(token);
           await Task.Delay(2000, token);

           while (!end && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
           {
               // Pozastavení běhu, pokud je aktivní pauza
               await CheckPauseAsync(token);
               

               
               UpdateRoundAndComboLabels(currentRound, currentComIndex);
               ComboClass combo = workout.GetCombos()[currentComIndex];
               bool isAdvice = combo.GetStrikes()[0] is AdviceClass;

               combo_label.Text = combo.GetName();
               UpdateComboLabelFontSize(combo.GetName().Length);
               UpdateStrikeLabelBackground(isAdvice);

               await PlaySoundAsync(combo, token);
               await Task.Delay(200, token);

               // Start executing the combo
               await ExecuteCombo(combo, isAdvice, token);
               
               currentComIndex++;
               if (currentComIndex == workout.TotalNumOfCombos())
               {
                   currentComIndex = 0;
                   remainingRounds--;
                   currentRound++;
                   divisor *= 1.5;
               }

               if (remainingRounds == 0)
               {
                   end = true;
               }

               skipped = false;
           }
       }
       catch (TaskCanceledException)
       {
           // Log or handle the cancellation if needed
       }
       finally
       {
           cts.Dispose(); // Clean up the cancellation token source
       }
   }


I tried preloading sounds and used await Task.Run to ease load on the main thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep
